# Why won't sklearn OneHotEncoder work with a single dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I'm trying to get a one-hot encoding of a single pandas dataframe column. Here's what I've got:

```
OH_encoder = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(X_train['time_of_day']))
```

When running this, I get a pretty big error stack, which can be summarized by the following:

`ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:`

I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is some sample data:

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['1234', '5678', '5678', '1234'], 
                   'time_of_day': ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Morning']})
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a Dataframe, but a Serie.

```
type(X_train['time_of_day'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

You can use X_train[['time_of_day']] (with [[ ]]):

```
type(X_train[['time_of_day']])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Like this

```
OH_cols_train = pd.DataFrame(OH_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[['time_of_day']]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If it says the method needs a 2D array just provide it with

```
X_train['time_of_day'].to_frame()
```